# How to remove ProgressBar Background?

Tags: android, styles, progress-bar

I have an app(Android 10+) in which I need to put a loading that disables user inputs.

As far as I coded, I found out I need to develop a ProgressBar

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_indeterminate"/>
```

Everything is working fine, except that, when i run my app, that's what appears (for privacy reason, the black dot is the image of the animation, do not consider it)

[image]

What i'm trying to achieve here is to remove the blank background of the dialog, making it transparent.
Is this possible? Do I have to conider a different Android layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling, i found a way to resolve this case via Java code.

```
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    alertDialog.show();
```